# get img src and name using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have no experience in javascript.
Basically i want to get image `src` and `aria-label` name using javascript. I try many scripts on console like this

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName("");
var src = image.getAttribute('src');
console.log(src);
```

but did't get solution. Can any one please tell me how i can get this.

[image]

[URl](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/cp0/e15/q65/c0.11.60.60/p60x60/13680834_1216301398414268_5977849811725918845_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoidCJ9&oh=6e36fc449be065f60098eb8c09437da9&oe=5880E2BF&__gda__=1487795153_ac0868d7736a2daea118e74963f7e067) is that i want to get using javascript.
Thanks

Comment: Why there isn't any classes specified?You should use `img profpic` class.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection`, not element...

Comment: This is facebook home page. I want to get facebook profile pic and name using javascript. I'v need to use it in my project.

Comment: There is no image tag showing in chrome inspector. Are you displaying image as background of i tag?

Comment: @ Eldo.Ob I know but i did't found any id here :(

Answer (score 1):

Your image is not in src attribute. It is in background-image.

```
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName("profpic")[0];
    var image= image.css('background-image');
    var src = image.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
    alert(src);
```

Comment: **Error**
VM347:2 Uncaught TypeError: image.css is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ VM347:2

Comment: Because .css() is a jQuery function [reference](http://api.jquery.com/css/) so you should include jQuery in your script.

Answer (score -1):

```
var elem=document.getElementsByClassName("img profpic")[0];
var match=elem.style.backgroundImage.match(/url\(\"(.*?)\"\)/)

var aria_label=elem.getAttribute("aria-label");
var background_url=match[1];
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".